# How to develop (and justify!) a nation born out of a lawless region of space?

Tags: space, government, space-warfare, governance

I am here once again for I am stuck on writing this part out... Long story short, a region of space, nicknamed the NCIZ 2 (second iteration of such thing happening); or "Non-Controlled Inhabited Zone". It is the home of multiple groups, such as pirates, but also intelligence agencies, and is de facto a buffer region between three nations at war. However, the exhaustion and economic crises made the nation originally controlling said region, pull out, resulting in a "NCIZ".

**How do I continue justifying the existence of said NCIZ?** As it is the epicenter of piracy and there is a proto-nation forming here, that is allied to one of the three nations at war, and that wages war against the nation that pulled out.

*For clarity purposes: the nation that pulled out is called the Stratocracy, the other nations at war: the Briserian Federation, and the Holy Briserian Empire.*

**I don't know how to continue with this NCIZ 2**, especially in the fight against the Stratocracy.
I hope it is clear enough of a question, as to not make you lose time trying to understand, while being sufficiently concise.

Thank you for reading, and thank you for your time!

Comment: The archetypal "Non-Controlled Inhabited Zone" in modern-ish history is of course the [Barbary Coast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbary_Coast). It was a den of piracy for centuries, and although the Ottoman Sultan sometimes bragged about controlling it, the inhabitants never considered themselves subjects of whoever reigned in Constantinople. By the end of the 17th century the Ottomans gave up and ceased pretending that they could appoint a pasha to rule the riotous natives. Eventually, there emerged the nations of Morocco, Algeria and Tunisia.

Comment: Hello! I see, it is indeed a very good example! However, how can I transpose it, in the midst of a religious, ethnic, and political conflict with three different nations? I suppose during the various conflicts in this region, and the numerous nations that came and went, it can still work, however, in my setting, it is also used as a proxy nation to wage war where they can't due to already atrocious losses of the war, and exploiting the "NCIZ" II's identity to help this proto-nation rising, and fighting. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Well, they did fight against whoever attempted to subjugate them, and they did form ephemeral alliances with whoever was ready to pay for the privilege. For example the great and glorious Holy Roman Emperor Charles V, who ruled a world-spanning empire upon which the sun never set, [tried to lay siege to Algiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algiers_expedition_(1541)) and was beaten. To get an idea of the adventurous history of the Barbary States, look how highly ambiguous is the phrase [battle of Algiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Algiers)...

Comment: Wow! I knew they had a very rich history, but wow, I didn't know it was this wide! Also, that siege by the HRE, never heard of it - it is a fascinating part of history! They had so much resources, and yet lost... This is indeed fascinating... I need to delve deeper and maybe take my inspiration from this interesting region as well. Thank you!

Comment: (Just a side-note: In that particular expedition, Charles V was acting in his persona as King of Spain, not as Holy Roman Emperor. The HRE could not care less about Algiers, and most definitely would not have spent one thaler. [Charles V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_V,_Holy_Roman_Emperor) was probably the most powerful man in the entire world history; he was at the same time Holy Roman Emperor, King of Spain, Archduke of Austria, Lord of the Netherlands, etc.)

Comment: What is your question? The title alludes to a nation being created and how this could happen in a lawless area, but you also say you want the NCIZ to continue existing. Which is it?

Comment: AlexP, I see, of course he wouldn't give much care to a region a bit far away, though  piracy might've bothered a bit? 
Demigan, hello! Indeed, it is a separate nation, that is *within* the NCIZ, and I would like the NCIZ to continue existing because, it seems like a waste of something that could make for an interesting sub-plot. A lawless area that is at the crossroads of a divided humanity. The nation is the result of politics, and the Federation wanting to wage a proxy war. The question is basically, how can I justify keeping it around, and not incorporating its whole into the new nation?

Comment: Are you talking about a region of space within a star system (eg the area around Ceres in the asteroid belt is the NCIZ) or are you talking about a region being one or more complete star systems?  Big difference, since within a star system the relative positions of the different bodies keep moving as they orbit.  On a related subject, what are the travel times between "nations"/"regions" given the technology available, including FTL?

Comment: It is a rather large part of space indeed; it has a few inhabited and inhabitable planets, and a large nebula where the HQ of both pirates and the nation are located in; FTL is heavily regulated, as civilian ships do not have the military variant of jump drives and can only jump to pre-entered coordinates, whereas the military one can jump anywhere, and successively by using a network of a sort of jumping network, so the travel time is trivial (think BSG's FTL jump for an equiv.)! [Here is the map!](https://briserian-dawn.fandom.com/wiki/Stratocracy?file=Stratocracy_8025.png)

Comment: Pirates eventually get old and tired...  The vicious fighters eventually kill each other off, leaving the more reasonable, less violent pirates...

Comment: I'm not sure what you are actually asking.

Comment: In my opinion human history has hundreds of examples of what you ask How is what you are describing/asking different from when empires/kingdoms   fall / break apart/  weaken etc?

Answer (score 5):

### Many of Your Cutthroats and Pirates Oppose the New Nation

They’ve been operating in this area for a very long time, and they’re not about to stop just because someone wants to try and create a new nation there.  Think of it like gang turf.  Gangs have their own borders, they don’t really care about the ones set by nations and countries.  And often, nation’s aren’t able to effectively keep these factions in line.  It’s organized crime, they’re essentially a “crime nation” of their own with their own army.  Criminal factions like this often prove very difficult for nations to deal with.  Perhaps you could even play the corrupt leaders card and show that some of the leaders within these nations have connections to these criminal factions who thrive in the NCIZ 2, so they leave it alone because it’s in their own private interests.

Comment: That is a fascinating aspect; I see, but the pirates are also quite beneficiary, as it disrupt very much the Stratocracy. The nation here is backed by the Federation, which is very powerful - relatively, especially as of "now". I can see the pirates not being under one banner, and breaking away eventually, and this would help keep the NCIZ 2 again. Also, it's been about 2 years within the setting that it appeared; would it be enough? And, what could be **the** thing that shatters the current alliance(s)? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @JustKherty If I’m understanding your comment correctly, it’s been two years since the new Federation nation appeared within the NCIZ 2.  Is that correct?  And are you talking about the alliances between the new Federation nation within the NCIZ II and the pirates/criminals within the NCIZ II?

Comment: Affirmative! I dunno if it makes sense though, but that's what I tried to say, aye! More specifically, there is a concealed massive station used by *both* the new nation, and the pirates, and thus they have to cohabit and be allied. I should probably edit the question to add this part?

Comment: @JustKherty That makes sense.  So if you want the new Federation nation and the pirates to eventually become disillusioned with each other, it could be pretty simple.  The pirates/criminals are going to do what’s best for them, so early on, kind of working with the new Federation nation might make sense.  Maybe the leadership within the new Federation nation has direct ties with the pirates.  Maybe later on, as the new Federation nation grows more powerful, the leadership decides to exert more control over the pirates.  They start expecting to receive tribute.  The pirates don’t like that.

Comment: ... therefore the gang **is** a nation. Right?

Answer (score 4):

There's a certain type of person that wants to live their life as they see fit, bound only by the moral rules they set for themselves and backed up by enough Firepower to make sure that those who might want to infringe on their life have to ask the question "If I mess around, am I going to find out?".

Naturally, this type of person is attracted to the NCIZ.

So, you have an area that is mainly occupied by well armed and fiercely independent individuals/groups.

Why does one of the factions not invade/lay claim to it?

Well, it represents a Triumvirate situation. An ingress into the NCIZ by one faction would cause a brief alliance between the other two factions to repel them,

Secondly - Cost/Benefit analysis - the area doesn't have a high degree of mineral wealth or resources where capturing would be advantageous - nor does it have any particular strategic value (other than a buffer zone) and the other 2 factions aside - the inhabitants would be more than prepared to stage a form of guerilla campaign - making sure that their losses were high.

Thus the area is allowed to exist - any move by one would be opposed by 2 or more and the cost is great with no real benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Once a "lawless" area has been established, it attracts certain types of people: criminals, non-believers, minor religious groups, and free thinkers. These people will band together to prevent the other nations from taking control of this area. Over time, the freedom of such an area will prove to be economically valuable. (See Christiania in Copenhagen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freetown_Christiania, Venice in Italy, and the Netherlands.) The Netherlands was a haven for people who thought differently.

As long as the piracy doesn't have too big of an impact, the surrounding nations won't take action as the cost of cleaning out the pirates will be far more than the benefit. But when a "lawless area" becomes wealthy, the surrounding nations will try to take it over, subject it to laws, and basically destroy why that area got wealthy. (See how a large corporation takes over a small one and destroys what made it work.)

It helps to have physical difficulties for the army/navy of the surrounding nation to operate. Both Venice and the Netherlands were built surrounded by water. Similarly, Helsinki has a marsh between it and Russia which made the Russian attack in 1939 very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

**Corruption.**

You're a Senator or whatever the equivalent is. On the motion to divert funding, patrols or aid into the NCIZ, you always vote no. You have above-board excuses but the real reason is because the lucrative trade in [insert illegal things here] brings you loads of cash which you use to finance your campaigns and grease other palms. You're not the only one. Loads of politicians are corrupted directly or indirectly by the illegal activities going on in the NCIZ which is why votes to do anything about it always fall on the floor.

We like to think in practical terms, that an area with resources and a tax base would of course fall into control of an empire that has more than enough military and police might to take on some pirates, but regardless of the government style, you only have to corrupt a relatively tiny number of powerful people in order to simply sway the political arm into not supporting such a campaign.

Politicians can continue to block action even as a lack of action causes visible damage to their own country and their own constituents. We can certainly find real-world examples of this. Maybe eventually the problems become bad enough that civil strife breaks out but certainly in the short term, corruption can turn the hand of government away from what looks like an obviously good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Plausible Deniability and Proxy War.

Let's say two of your factions have tense relations with each other.  But for whatever reason (treaties, not wanting to escalate tensions, etc.) they cannot officially move against each other.

However if they support this proto-nation, and the proto-nation or the people within it attack, then there is no issue.  They have not broken any of their agreements, but they still put pressure on the other faction without directly escalating to full scale war.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of reference points from US history:

- The "Wild West" ─ gambling and prostitution were widespread, among other things.
- Hollywood ─ it started as a place for film-makers to avoid the enforcement of patents on cameras and other film-making equipment.

So essentially, people will move to a lawless place because they want to make money doing something that is illegal, heavily regulated, or heavily taxed in the more established civilisation.

Answer (score 0):

### Invading it would spread the attacker too thin

While the NCIZ is inhabited, it is not inhabited in the same way that the 3 major nations are.  It is a very large territory with a comparatively low population density.  While the region as a whole has a population large enough to constitute a proper nation in its own right, it's population and industrial density is so low that it would take a massive fleet and considerable logistics to actually occupy any significant portion of the NCIZ.

Even if the Stratocracy were to try to invade the NCIZ, the NCIZ colonies are small, and thier assets mobile.  They would have to push deep into the NCIZ hunting down small and scattered targets leaving their supply lines exposed to the exact kind of piracy that the NCIZ specializes in.  Spreading out to occupy any significant part of the region would also mean breaking up thier armada into a lot of smaller task forces; so, if either of the other two nations were to send a fleet to help the NCIZ, the Stratocracy would not have enough concentration of forces anywhere to stop a unified fleet, and they would lose a lot of assets trying to scramble to reform into a cohesive fighting force.  Lastly, because the Stratocracy is so busy fighting the other nations, it simply can't spare the ships required for a meaningful invasion.

Since NCIZ's ships are too small, scattered, and lack a central command structure, the NCIZ can't launch a meaningful assault on the Stratocracy either because any single planet inside the Stratocracy is far too heavily fortified for any little pirate task force to have a chance against; so, even though they are formally at war with the Stratocracy, they don't pose a major threat inside of the Stratocracy's actual territory compared to the other nations.

### How they transitioned into a Nation

Quite frankly, so many nations today started off as lawless frontiers, it almost doesn't need any real justification.  During the age of colonialism, about 1 in 4 of all colonists were criminals sent to various penal colonies across what are today the United States, Australia, and many of the Philippian and Caribbean Islands.  Most of these penal colonies were work-release programs such that the murderers, rapist, smugglers, counterfeiters, and prisoners of war sent to these places were set free in the New World after thier terms of imprisonment were completed leading to a proportionally massive subculture of lawlessness.

But this state of being never lasts forever.  Once a criminal starts to amass wealth, power, and influence, he starts to have to worry less about where his next meal-ticket is coming from and more about how he will hang onto what he has amid the chaos of competing outlaws... so the well to do outlaws begin to form alliances.
And these alliances are held together by rules which evolve into a system of law and order to protect those in power.  And soon, yesterday's criminals become tomorrow's politicians who formalize the laws and structure of the land into a formal government.